# How to judge zero value of golang reflect

Tags: reflection, go, zero

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    var p1 *string = nil
    var v interface{} = p1
    val := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(v))
    if v == nil {
        fmt.Printf("NULL")
    } else {
        if val.CanInterface() {
            fmt.Printf("if is %v\n", val.Interface())
        }
    }
}
```

This program's output is：

```
···

panic: reflect: call of reflect.Value.CanInterface on zero Value

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0xd65a0, 0xc82005e000)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3e6
reflect.Value.CanInterface(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:897 +0x62

···
```

What's the matter？ Why if `v == nil` is `false`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`v` isn't nil, it contains a `*string`.

However, if you want to check if a reflect value is valid (non-zero), you can use [`val.IsValid()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.IsValid) to check.

Also if you want to check if it's nil, you can check `if val.Kind() == reflect.Ptr && val.IsNil() {}`.

A little demo:

```
func main() {
    var p1 *string = nil
    var v interface{} = p1
    // this will return an invalid value because it will return the Elem of a nil pointer.
    //val := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(v))
    val := reflect.ValueOf(v) // comment this to see the difference.
    if !val.IsValid() {
        fmt.Printf("NULL")
    } else {
        if val.CanInterface() {
            fmt.Printf("if is %#+v (%v)\n", val.Interface(), val.Interface() == nil)
        }
    }
    fmt.Println(v.(*string) == nil)
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/lmf0t3MVhx)

Comment: you mean  var v interface{} = o; the v is not the o, only the pointer to the o?

Comment: @upduan it is the `o`, and in that case `o` is a `*string`, that's why `v.(*string) == nil` works.